# Java How to create objects of class without name

Tags: java, new-operator

This is a pretty simple question but I was wondering about making objects of classes without names. For example, if I had a class 'Zombie' how would I create a new one without assigning a new name each time (e.g., `Zombie zombie1 = new Zombie();`)

Comment: Do you want a data structure to save the references to these objects?

Comment: How are you going to refer to the objects if they don't have a name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new Zombie()` will create a new zombie instance. You do not, however, have to assign it to a local variable or data member if you don't want to. You could, for instance, accumulate these zombies in a collection:

```
List<Zombie> undeadLegion = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    undeadLegion.add(new Zombie());
}
```

Comment: +! for descriptive variable names... :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is [name binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding): the association of data with an identifier.

The most common use of binding is to determine the *scope* of a variable.  Bound data is guaranteed by the language to exist (say "in scope").  In Java, the converse is not true: unbound data might still exist on the heap before garbage collection.  However, there is no way to access this data, because you have no way to identify it (short of deep magic involving the garbage collector).

You can create unbound data just by writing `new Zombie()`.  You do not have to give it a specific name; it could be an unnamed member of a (named) array:

```
// Create a new ArrayList<> and bind it to the name list.
List<Zombie> list = new ArrayList<Zombie>();

// Create new Zombie objects, but do not name them.
// Instead, add them to the list.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    list.add(new Zombie());
}
```

You can also pass an object directly to a function.  It won't be bound to any names in the caller's scope, but it will be bound in the callee's scope:

```
void a()
{
    b(new Zombie());
}

void b(Zombie z)
{
}
```

Here, the `new Zombie()` is not named in `a` at all -- but once it's passed to `b`, it is bound to `z`.

Finally, you can create an object and do exactly nothing with it:

```
new Zombie();
```

It will immediately be unreachable unless its constructor stores a reference to itself somewhere.  However, side effects such as printing to the console will still be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Objects don't have names.  There is no way to assign a name to the object, nor can you find out what it was at runtime (with help from debug information)

What you may have meant, is how do I avoid declaring a named reference to an object.

The simplest way it to use the reference as an expression like

```
System.out.println(new Zombie());
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't have names. Variables have names. You don't have to store the result of `new` into a variable: you can pass it directly as a parameter for example, or just throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a new object to a method or such, you can just use the constructor call (`new Zombie()`) without assigning it to a variable.

For example, if you have method called `doThingsWithZombie()` that takes a `Zombie` object, you can do the following:

```
doThingsWithZombie(new Zombie());
```

You could also add the new object to a list:

```
LinkedList<Zombie> zombieList = new LinkedList<Zombie>();
zombieList.add(new Zombie()); // Add a zombie
zombieList.add(new Zombie()); // Add a zombie
zombieList.get(0) // Gets the first zombie
```